# Can every differentiable scalar function be written as a divergence of some vector field?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

My question is simple: can every differentiable function $f$ defined on a bounded, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ be written as a divergence of some vector field ? That is, given the vector field $\mathbf{F}$, you can write:$$f=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}$$
Is this always possible? How to prove it?

Comment: You really want to get into defining "differentiable" when the domain is not open?  Perhaps for some points $a,b$ every path going from $a$ to $b$ in the set has infinite length... ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve )

Answer (score 2):

Sure. For example, supposing the intersection of the domain with every vertical line is an interval containing zero, you could just take

$$ \mathbf F(x,y,z) = (0, 0, \int_0^z f(x,y,t)\,dt) $$

For a domain of a more complex shape it could be more tedious to patch a solution together from smaller ones, but the *existence* of an $\mathbf F$ isn't really at risk.

Comment: you mean $z$ in place of $x$, right?

Comment: @user211517: Yes, of course. Fixed.

Comment: why did you make that assumption?

Comment: @user211517: The assumption makes sure that $f(x,y,t)$ actually exists at every point where the integral needs it. Otherwise you'd need to choose different zero points and apply some extra footwork to make sure the result is continuous. It's probably easiest just to start by extending $f$ arbitrarily to all of $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\int_0^xf(x,y,z)dx\right)^{'}_x+\left(\frac{1}{3}\int_0^yf(x,y,z)dy\right)^{'}_y+\left(\frac{1}{3}\int_0^zf(x,y,z)dz\right)^{'}_z.$$

Comment: so good...does this complete the proof?

Comment: I think so, at least it gives the basic idea how to do.

Comment: This is not correct as the term on the right-hand side is not a divergence...